# Window title bar appears transparent issue (Not really transparent)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I am trying to make my app have more 'flat' feel so I think it is a good idea to hide the title bar.

However, in reality `titlebarAppearsTransparent` seems only remove the title bar shadow but not make the title bar truly transparent.

Before using any code to modify the title bar,

[image]

After adding the following code (starting have a better feel),

```
self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

[image]

Setting the background color to white,

```
    self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
    self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

[image]

This is certainly not what I want. I thought I just turned the title bar transparent to `true`. What is going on here?

Any hint or comment is appreciated and thanks for your time viewing this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try add:

```
self.window?.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
```

> When set, the content view consumes the full size of the window; it
>   can be combined with other window style masks, but is only respected
>   for windows with a title bar. Using this mask opts in to layer
>   backing. Use the contentLayoutRect or contentLayoutGuide to lay out
>   views underneath the title bar-toolbar area

If you don't want to keep the title bar at all, you can also added:

```
self.window?.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
```

> The window hides the title and moves the toolbar up into the area
>   previously occupied by the title.

You might also wanted to add this in order to move the window by dragging its content view:

```
self.window?.movableByWindowBackground = YES
```

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the window is movable by
>   clicking and dragging anywhere in its background. The value of this
>   property is YES when the window is movable by clicking and dragging
>   anywhere in its background; otherwise, NO.

Comment: Wow, this does work! I really should read the doc more carefully. Thanks.