# Same look for title bar and non-native toolbar?

Tags: macos, qt

My app looks so:

[image]

I want it to look so:

[image]

I.e. same background color, no border line between title bar and toolbar.

Yes, It seems I know how to do this using native toolbar ([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder)). But I would prefer to avoid using native toolbars if it's possible. This toolbar is created by `Qt` `QML` code. It's cross-platform and is used on Windows/Mac/Linux.

Is it possible?

P.S. I'm not very much familiar with native macOS programming, so some code examples in `C++` or `Objective-C` are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944792/window-title-bar-appears-transparent-issue-not-really-transparent) I have found that `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` + `transparent title bar` does the trick for me. I.e.

```
self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
self.window?.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
```